# Android Play Store - app identifier is case-sensitive?

Tags: android, google-play, fully-qualified-naming

I have always thought that the unique backwards-domain identifier of an app is not case-sensitive, but it appears, it is?

Answer (score 7):

It is case sensitive. This is most likely because of:

1. Java is case sensitive, so its package names are logically case sensitive as well.
2. Google uses UNIX based servers, which are also case sensitive by default (by and large at least) when it comes to URLs.

Comment: it's a shame that they did not use mod_rewrite to make urls more friendly like apple